# My Javascript Code isn't detecting input

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have been trying to get input to work on my javascript code and it won't detect input no matter what! I've been checking everywhere and it doesn't work!

```html
<!Doctype HTML>
<html>

<head>
 <title>Input Test</title>
</head>

<body>

 <!--<button onClick="main()">Start Game</button>-->

 <p id = "test"> </p>
 
</body>

<script>

 main();
 function main() { 
  create();
 }
 
 function create() {
  
  var keystate;
  keystate = {};
  // keep track of keyboard presses
  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) {
   keystate[evt.keyCode] = true;
  });
  document.addEventListener("keyup", function(evt) {
   delete keystate[evt.keyCode];
  });
  
  var Up_Key = 38;
  
  setInterval("update()", 100);
  
 }
 
 function update() {
  
  //document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "twerks";
  
  if (keystate[Up_Key]) {
   document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "works";
  }
  
 }

</script>

</html>
```

I've been using some tutorials and I just want input detection.

Comment: You might start with valid HTML, script elements are only valid within the head or body (though likely browsers will move the element into the body).

Comment: You’re defining `keystate` and `Up_Key` in `create`, and using them in `update` where they are no longer in scope. Make `keystate` and `Up_Key` global. Your friendly browser error console ought to have told you this.

Comment: where is the friendly browser error console

Comment: Windows OS: CTRL & SHIFT + J will open your browsers console. It will display the error log.

Comment: @NewToJS—not for me, F12 works.

Comment: Up_Key is out of scope. I am sure your developer console has an error message about it

Comment: how do i put it in scope

Comment: @RobG Or F12. I'm sure that used to open Inspect Element... Could be wrong but CTRL & SHIFT + J should also work. I'm using Chrome.

Comment: i opened the console and it is saying keystate is undefined

Comment: what do i need to do to define my keystate

Comment: If you don't understand what undefined is I can only recommend you research the basics of javascript so you have a better understanding of what it is you're dealing with and understand how to achieve your goal.

Comment: i understand what undefined means now but the tutorial does not show what to do with the keystate variable other than that, ive been using the source code as a reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables `keystate` and `Up_Key` are defined inside the `create` function, but you're trying to use them inside another function named `update`. They'll be `undefined` there, since it's in another scope.

If you declare those variables outside the functions, your code will work fine.

It's better to encapsulate all your code in an IIFE (Immediately invoked function expression), so you don't polute the global scope, with global variables. As Google says:

> An immediately-invoked function expression (or IIFE, pronounced "iffy") is a JavaScript design pattern which produces a lexical scope using JavaScript's function scoping.

Here is your code updated and working:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Input Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="test"></p>
</body>

<script>
  (function() {
    var keystate = {};
    var Up_Key = 38;

    main();

    function main() {
      create();
    }

    function create() {
      // keep track of keyboard presses
      document.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) {
        keystate[evt.keyCode] = true;
      });
      document.addEventListener("keyup", function(evt) {
        delete keystate[evt.keyCode];
      });

      setInterval(update, 100);
    }

    function update() {
      if (keystate[Up_Key]) {
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "works";
      }
    }
  })();
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: yayyyyyy, it works, thanks, i didnt have a really good understanding of javascript before this because i learned Java programming first so this was a little wierd to me, i now realise that the languages are very similar,     Thanks

Comment: @Flame6332 if my answer was useful for you, please, click on the arrow to upvote it, and on the `V` to mark it as the accepted one! thanks :)

Comment: Ok, I had already upvoted it and checked it as complete, Thanks Again :)